# How to avoid duplicate sequential numbers when multiple records are inserted at the exact same time?

Tags: mysql, laravel, increment, multi-tenant

My Laravel application is multi-tenant, same-table & same-database, using a `team_id` foreign key.

For every team, each of their resources have a sequential `number` that's manually incremented and assigned when creating a resource, as shown below.

```
/**
 * Handle the "creating" event.
 *
 * @param  Product  $product
 * @return void
 */
public function creating(Product $product)
{
    $product->number = $product->team->products()->withTrashed()->max('number') + 1;
}
```

But, as it turns out, when there are multiple requests at the exact same time for the same team and type of resource, those resources will get the same number.

What's the best way of getting around this, without being too messy?

---

I was thinking of checking and correcting the number right after the resource is created, but that's kinda messy, and it results in 1 or 2 extra queries for every request. But, that might still not work if the multiple requests happen at the exact same time.

Comment: What's wrong with the default auto-incremented primary key number, [documentaiton under primary keys](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)?

Comment: @danblack Because it's not exactly a primary key. It needs to be unique per `team_id`.

Comment: You might want to use a UUID. https://github.com/ramsey/uuid https://www.uuidtools.com/what-is-uuid

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix it, is to simply create a [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions), when you create the Product. This will SQL lock your table, until the lock is released and therefor have the correct data.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $product->save();
}, $attempts = 5);
```

Comment: And this won't cause an error/block for the other requests at the same time?

Comment: yes it will but the transaction should be almost instantaneously.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate? Because I still want the multiple requests to be successful every time they occur at the same time.

Comment: The save operation is fairly quick almost instantanious, combine it with a max call that also is quick it will not lock up the database for long and probably not cause lock timeouts unless you get bombarded with requests. Try it out, and see if you error reporting acts up.